# How to sort a dictionary in python by keys (without creating a duplicate dictionary)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary  with respect to the keys.
eg:

```py
a = {3:2, 2:1, 1:6, 6:5}
```

I want to convert it to this without importing any package:

```py
a = {1:6, 2:1, 3:2, 6:5}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: if its python 3.7+ `ordered = dict(sorted(a.items()))`

Answer (score -1):

You can't really sort a dictionary by keys, but you can enumerate the dictionary by its keys sorted as seen below. Or you can [manipulate the dict to a sorted OrderedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) as @Stef commented.

```
for key in sorted(a.keys()):
    print(key,a[key])
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I said - I merely pointed out that the question was a duplicate. Since Python 3.7, `dict` have order. So you could just write `sorted_dict = dict(sorted(unsorted_dict.items()))`.

Comment: See also: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score -2):

See below (the solution is using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which is part of core python and not an external package)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = {3:2,2:1,1:6,6:5}
b = {k:a[k] for k in sorted(a.keys())}
print(b)
```

outout

```
{1: 6, 2: 1, 3: 2, 6: 5}
```